# BPG image format on Android

Tags: android, image, image-compression

I think somebody heard something about a new format of images - [BPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Portable_Graphics). Can i handle it on Android, any ideas?

PS: BPG is really interesting format, for example, just checkout [difference with jpeg](http://bellard.org/bpg/lena.html)

**UPDATE** another examples of difference [here](http://screenshotcomparison.com/comparison.php?id=103941) and [here](http://screenshotcomparison.com/comparison.php?id=109532)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "handle it"?  Are you trying to write code to decode and display it yourself?

Comment: @pjco, Yes, by "handle it" i meant to decode and display image.

Answer (score 5):

The BPG format is not supported by Android natively.

I've made a small application for Android that decompresses BPG images. You can have a look here: https://github.com/alexandruc/android-bpg, maybe you can reuse some of the code.

For use in the browser, there is a javascript decoder available in the [source package](http://bellard.org/bpg/).

Comment: Very nice, but about as much use as a chocolate teapot under the GPL, sadly. Any thoughts on putting this under a permissive license?

Comment: @barneypitt switched to MIT license. That should give you enough flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this format is supported, yet, according to the [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core)

But you should give it a try.

Note:
If you meant browser support, you should update your question to let everybody know it.

Edit:
After some tests, I couldn't manage to make it work, even on Lollipop.

Conclusion, it is not supported, yet.

Comment: No, i mean no browser, but media format. As just image format "from box" it not supported, yes, but this format based on HEVC, which supported by Android. So maybe it's possible to implement supporting of this format?

Comment: @Gorcyn, did you manage to compile the BPG library for Android?